# Compatibility layer to parse XML and HTML documents?

Tags: java, parsing, xslt, transformation

I'm making an aggregator for restaurants menus in Java. I'm looking for the best way to extract the content of documents formatted in various ways: some restaurants provide an RSS feed, others provide an HTML table, for others you have to compile the result displayed on multiple pages...

What I'm looking for, is a way to describe the transformation necessary to go from the source document to an easily-parsable format. Of course this transformation will have to be different and custom-made for every data source, but that's not a problem.

I know I could write a Java adapter for each restaurant, but I'm looking for a simpler, more standard solution. Basically something like XSLT but more flexible.

Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0   ( simple, standard and more flexible than XSLT 1.0 )

Comment: Also: take a look at Dimitre's page's on functional programming in XSLT: http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/